# Regex pattern that matches that first pattern of the file

Tags: php, regex

I'm having a hard time getting the regex pattern that can get the 123456abcde_ and it's also optional on the filename? I'm using the preg_replace and one of the requirements is the pattern
that can get the 123456abcde_ and replace it with an empty string, btw here is my code and sample pattern of the filename.

```
123456abcde_get-thisValue_more details - specific_20200728173715594600.zip
123456abcde_get-thisValue_more details_20200728173715594600.zip
123456abcde_getthisValue_more details - specific_20200728173715594600.zip
123456abcde_getthisValue_more details_20200728173715594600.zip
123456abcde_get-thisValue_20200728173715594600.zip
123456abcde_getthisValue_20200728173715594600.zip
get-thisValue_more details - specific_20200728173715594600.zip
get-thisValue_more details_20200728173715594600.zip
getthisValue_more details - specific_20200728173715594600.zip
getThisValue_more details_20200728173715594600.zip
get-thisValue_20200728173715594600.zip
getthisValue_20200728173715594600.zip
```

And this is my code and the target output of this is the get-thisValue or getthisValue.

```
$filename = '123456abcde_get-thisValue_more details - specific_20200728173715594600.zip';
$pattern = '/^([\da-z])\1*_/m';
$prefix = preg_replace($pattern, '', $filename);
$prefix = substr($prefix, 0, strpos($prefix, '_'));
echo $prefix;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments to this and the other answers and the assumption, that the code you want to extract, can not contain any space characters, I came up with this pattern, that works for all the examples you posted in your question and at the regex101 site:

```
$filenames = "123456abcde_get-thisValue_more details - specific_20200728173715594600.zip
123456abcde_get-thisValue_more details_20200728173715594600.zip
123456abcde_getthisValue_more details - specific_20200728173715594600.zip
123456abcde_getthisValue_more details_20200728173715594600.zip
123456abcde_get-thisValue_20200728173715594600.zip
123456abcde_getthisValue_20200728173715594600.zip
get-thisValue_more details - specific_20200728173715594600.zip
get-thisValue_more details_20200728173715594600.zip
getthisValue_more details - specific_20200728173715594600.zip
getThisValue_more details_20200728173715594600.zip
get-thisValue_20200728173715594600.zip
getthisValue_20200728173715594600.zip
familyroot_organizationcode_test by me_20220718120036254943.zip
familyroot_organization-code_test by me - local_20220718120036254943.zip
familyroot_organization-code_20220718120036254943.zip
123456_organizationcode_test by me_20220718120036254943.zip
123456_organization-code_test by me - local_20220718120036254943.zip
123456_organization-code_20220718120036254943.zip
organization-code_test by me - local_20220718120036254943.zip
organization-code_test by me_20220718120036254943.zip
organizationcode_test by me - local_20220718120036254943.zip
organizationcode_test by me_20220718120036254943.zip
organization-code_20220718120036254943.zip
organizationcode_20220718120036254943.zip
familyroot_code_test by me_20220718120036254943.zip
familyroot_code_test by me - local_20220718120036254943.zip
familyroot_code_20220718120036254943.zip
123456_code_test by me_20220718120036254943.zip
123456_code_test by me - local_20220718120036254943.zip
123456_code_20220718120036254943.zip
code_test by me - local_20220718120036254943.zip
code_test by me_20220718120036254943.zip
code_test by me - local_20220718120036254943.zip
code_test by me_20220718120036254943.zip
code_20220718120036254943.zip
code_20220718120036254943.zip";

$pattern = '/^(?:[\da-z]+_)?([^_\s]+)_.*$/m';
$prefix = preg_match_all($pattern,$filenames, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

The first part within the non-capturing parenthesis with the question mark behind it is the optional prefix consisting of one or more digits or lowercase characters followed by an underline character (no dashes or spaces allowed). The question mark behind the closing parenthesis makes this group optional, meaning it matches the empty string if there is no prefix.

The second part within the capturing parenthesis stands for 'one or more characters not equal to the underline character nor any space characters' matching your desired "get-thisValue" or "getthisValue" or "code" or "organisationcode" or "organisation-code". The difference is made by the 'nor any space characters' here!

Finally the following underline character and the '.*' match the rest of the filename all the way to the end of the line (indicated by the $ at the end of the pattern).

So we have a pattern, that matches the complete file name and picks up the interesting part in the first capturing group that gets printed by the last line.

You can actually watch this code in action [here](https://onlinegdb.com/h-ZBH1b63). There you can fork it, which will make it editable for you and then play around with code to your liking.

Hope that solves your problem!

Comment: I try it, but several filenames did not match the pattern. the goal is to match the account prefix and an example of that is familyroot and 123456. kindly check the link, please. [Filename](https://regex101.com/r/jJS4St/1)

Comment: @EazylleConcepcion I guess you need to be more exact about your specification what exactly you want to identify in those filenames. You wrote: `And this is my code and the target output of this is the get-thisValue or getthisValue.` And that is, what my regex is doing - at least for the examples you provided in the question. In your list of filenames from the link in your comment there are names with 3 underline-characters and also the dash (-) seams to be part of the prefix. Thus I really don't know how to help you further without exactly knowing what you want.

Comment: @EazylleConcepcion Also, if you do a multi-line-search like you do at this link you posted, you need to add the new-line-character to the second square brackets character group, otherwise the regex will cross lines and everything gets garbled anyway: `^([\da-z-]+_)?([^_\n]+)_(.*)$`

Comment: @EazylleConcepcion So... I edited my answer taking into account the additional examples from the regex101 site and your comments here and the other answers. I hope this now does, what you need!

Answer (score 0):

The changes in the code is `$pattern = '/^123456abcde_/m';`.If the string is already known then you need to simply match the with the hardcoded string which want to replace.

```
<?php
 $filename = '123456abcde_get-thisValue_more details - specific_20200728173715594600.zip';
 $pattern = '/^123456abcde_/m';
 $prefix = preg_replace($pattern, '', $filename);
 $prefix = substr($prefix, 0, strpos($prefix, '_'));
 echo $prefix;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to get the value:

```
^(?:[\da-z]+_)?\K[^_\n]+
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:[\da-z]+_)?` Optionally match 1+ digits or lowercase chars a-z
- `\K` Clear the match buffer
- `[^_\n]+` Match 1+ chars other than _ or a newline

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5KqWoe/1) | [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/WqP2G)

```
$re = '/^(?:[\da-z]+_)?\K[^_\n]+/m';
$str = '123456abcde_get-thisValue_more details - specific_20200728173715594600.zip
123456abcde_get-thisValue_more details_20200728173715594600.zip
123456abcde_getthisValue_more details - specific_20200728173715594600.zip
123456abcde_getthisValue_more details_20200728173715594600.zip
123456abcde_get-thisValue_20200728173715594600.zip
123456abcde_getthisValue_20200728173715594600.zip
get-thisValue_more details - specific_20200728173715594600.zip
get-thisValue_more details_20200728173715594600.zip
getthisValue_more details - specific_20200728173715594600.zip
getThisValue_more details_20200728173715594600.zip
get-thisValue_20200728173715594600.zip
getthisValue_20200728173715594600.zip
123456abcde_get-thisValue_more details - specific_20200728173715594600.zip';


preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => get-thisValue
    [1] => get-thisValue
    [2] => getthisValue
    [3] => getthisValue
    [4] => get-thisValue
    [5] => getthisValue
    [6] => get-thisValue
    [7] => get-thisValue
    [8] => getthisValue
    [9] => getThisValue
    [10] => get-thisValue
    [11] => getthisValue
    [12] => get-thisValue
)
```

Comment: can you check this please, when I tried to use the pattern but they did not get the value, kindly check this pattern, please [File Format](https://regex101.com/r/8Ds525/1)

Comment: @EazylleConcepcion What you do want to match in all those examples?

Comment: the organization-code, organizationcode, code but this is one of the value on the get-thisValue. fyi

Comment: @EazylleConcepcion Try `^(?:(?:\d+|familyroot)_)?\K[\da-z-]+(?=(?:[\w-]+(?:\h+[\w-]+)*)?_\d+\.zip$)` https://regex101.com/r/tsXl4J/1